# Count all sequences of characters

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an Array of Characters ' A ' and ' B '

Whats a smart way to count the ' Runs '

example :

AABBBAAAABBAB

should be 6 because there are 6 runs as seen below.

```
1    2    3     4   5  6
AA   BBB  AAAA  BB  A  B
```

tried something like:

```
if (!(sortedRuns.get(i) == sortedRuns.get(i+1))) {
    runsAmount++;
}
```

but obviously run into 'out of bound problems'

Comment: `i<whateverLength-1` could help with `out of bound problems`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue

```
e.g char array      A A B B C C
    array positions 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

when you reach at the position 5 then `sortedRuns.get(i+1)` mean `5+1=6` which doesn't exist hence the exception

Solution

1.) Traverse the array

2.) Increment run if char changes and assign new char to `temp` char

```
String s="AABBBAAAABBAB";
int run=1;
// fetch first char
char temp=s.charAt(0);

// traverse char array
for (char ch : s.toCharArray()) {
    // assign value of new char to temp and increment run 
    // when value of char changes
    if (ch!=temp) {
        run++;
        temp=ch;
    }

}
System.out.println(run);
```

Output:

```
6
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an auxiliar variable to save the last character. Then increment when a new character is different from my auxiliar variable, then update this variable. Easy and not out of bounds exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression. 
/(.)\1*/ gives 6 matches.

(.) matches any character. 
\1* then matches as many of the first character as possible.

Java Example:

```
final String regex = "(.)\\1*";
final String string = "AABBBAAAABBAB";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

int count = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
    count ++;
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
    for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
    }
}
System.out.println("Match count: " + count);
```

This has the advantage of working with any character string.

Comment: @AndersPedersen I've added a Java example as requested.

Answer (score 0):

u can try this easy one-liner:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s="AABBBAAAABBAB";

    int charCount = s.length() - s.replaceAll("A", "").length();
    System.out.println(charCount);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```